# How to prevent users from choosing a date greater than today?

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

## Help me disabling the users from choosing a date greater than today

Currently, users can choose any date even greater than today to register a patient. They are supposed to be able to register the patient into the system who had their treatment few days back but not for upcoming treatment. In short, I wish to disable the users from choosing a date greater than today. So, here's what I have :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datefield').datetimepicker({ 'dateFormat': 'dd-mm-yy' });
    $("#register_date").val( $dss.getDate("dd-mm-yyyy jj:nn") )
    if ($("#cancel_date").val() == "" ){ //00-00-0000 00:00
        $("#cancel_date").val( $dss.getDate("dd-mm-yyyy jj:nn") ) 
    } 
    user_name = "<?php echo $_SESSION['USER_NAME']; ?>"
    user_id = "<?php echo $_SESSION['USER_ID']; ?>"
    
    ipdMC();
     
    $("#cancel_id").val(user_id);

    ///--> getLabStatus();  
    physio_list_start();
    
    $$live();
});
```

and this as my reference :

```
*$(document).ready(function (){

    var todaysDate = new Date(); // Gets today's date

    // Max date attribute is in "YYYY-MM-DD".  Need to format today's date accordingly

    var year = todaysDate.getFullYear();                        // YYYY
    var month = ("0" + (todaysDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);  // MM
    var day = ("0" + todaysDate.getDate()).slice(-2);           // DD

    var maxDate = (day +"-"+ month +"-"+ year); // Results in "YYYY-MM-DD" for today's date 
 
    // Now to set the max date value for the calendar to be today's date
    $('.inspectionDate input').attr('max',maxDate);

});*
```

Comment: have you read the documentation for the datetimepicker? https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#mindate

Comment: there will mindate, just set it as today.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra do you mean “max date”? The OP said disable choosing date _greater than_ today.

Comment: as @evolutionxbox said, i need to disable the greater date than today from being chosen by the users

Answer (score 1):

you can use mindate to make the datetimepicker disabled to the date greater than today

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datefield').datetimepicker({ 
          'dateFormat': 'dd-mm-yy',
           'maxDate': 0  
     });
    $("#register_date").val( $dss.getDate("dd-mm-yyyy jj:nn") )
    if ($("#cancel_date").val() == "" ){ //00-00-0000 00:00
        $("#cancel_date").val( $dss.getDate("dd-mm-yyyy jj:nn") ) 
    } 
    user_name = "<?php echo $_SESSION['USER_NAME']; ?>"
    user_id = "<?php echo $_SESSION['USER_ID']; ?>"

    ipdMC();

    $("#cancel_id").val(user_id);

    ///--> getLabStatus();  
    physio_list_start();

    $$live();
});
```

but make if you use  javascript your timezone will be using client side timezone so be careful

Comment: omg you saved my life! thank you so much! and for your warning, i'll keep that in  mind!